# Sonar Scanner T-SQL unable to parse file

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

i'm using SonarQube Developer edition 7.3 with SonarScanner 3.2. During parsing my T-SQL code i've some errors like

```
WARN: Unable to parse file 'xxxxx.sql' : Parse error at line 7 column 4:

1:
2:
3:
4:
5:
6: CREATE TRIGGER [xxxx]
7: ON DATABASE
       ^

WARN: Unable to parse file 'xxxx.sql' : Parse error at line 34 column 16:

34:   WITH NOWAIT, SETERROR;
```

Thanks
Giuseppe

Comment: See [this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/parse-error-in-sonar-scanner-for-tsql-files/1598) community discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I have got same problem too me. I don't understand anything from log messages.

Comment: Hi, it seems that there are bugs in T-SQL parsing. https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-scanner-t-sql-unable-to-parse-file/3110

Comment: Thanks my friend. Maybe It can be. I will follow this job.